# Traducción para la estructura objeto + forma base

Tags: traducción, gramática, subjuntivo, infinitivo

Estuve leyendo en un libro algunos ejemplos sobre esta estructura y al principio había pensado en una sola traducción, pero después me di cuenta que podía usar otra.

> *She **lets** her children **stay** up very late.*

Mis opciones son:

> *Ella deja que sus niños se **queden** hasta muy tarde.*
>   *Ella deja a sus niños **quedarse** hasta muy tarde.*

La primera usa el subjuntivo, la segunda el infinitivo, pero creo que la segunda es la forma correcta, ¿o son ambas correctas con significados distintos?

Comment: A mí ambas me suenan igual de bien y me transmiten la misma información.

Comment: Ambas formas son correctas. Dos correcciones: "quedarse" significa "stay"; si lo que quieres decir es "stay up" tienes que especificar **"quedarse despiertos"** o **"quedarse levantados"**. Por otra parte, la preposición **a** es obligatoria antes de "sus niños" en la segunda frase.

Comment: @Yay Sí, el *stay up* en realidad es un verbo compuesto. Lo había mirado de otra forma. En la segunda opción olvidé la *a*, ahí lo edité. Igual de todas formas me gustaría ver una interpretación de sus significados, si es que algjuien desea dar alguna respuesta.

Comment: «...pero después me di cuenta DE QUE podía usar otra».

Comment: @TeachingTom Al momento de escribir, solamente dejo que el texto fluya. No me complicaré la vida hilando fino en el queísmo y el dequeísmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Básicamente, hay ciertos verbos que en inglés no se siguen por el marcador infinitivo *to*. Algunos de estos son: *let, make, see, hear, feel, watch* y *notice*.

Para ellos sigue siendo una forma indicativa de expresar la afirmación, pero para nosotros, así como lo sugería, existen dos formas empleando el infinitivo y el subjuntivo.

Answer (score 1):

La primera está correcta y es la forma más usada estructuralmente. La segunda, aunque correcta también, a un nativo le 'suena' un poco raro, en mi opinión.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo. Prefiero usar el subjuntivo en vez de la segunda opción del infinitivo.